# Operations with arrays in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector, matrix, calculus

I have this 2-dimensional array

```
x=[62,29,64;
    63,31,62;
    65,29,60;
    63,29,62;
    63,31,62;];
```

1st element in each column is R, 2nd is G, 3rd is B from the formula below.

I would like a function to compute the following operation:

[image]

So far, my function definition looks like this:

```
function[distance]=RGB_dist(x,y)

  distance=sqrt(sum(((x-y)*[3;4;2]).^2,2));

end
```

Tested with the matrix above, `disp(RGB_dist(x,x))` outputs only zeroes. That must happen because he is calculating the distance between same vectors. How do I do to calculate the distance between any two vector(lines) from my matrix. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: which are the two vectors between which you need the distance , are they pairs of rows of `x`

Comment: Does [This matlab page](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/colon.html) not contain the answer to your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For two arbitrary lines (e.g. line 1 and line 2) do:

```
RGB_dist(x(1,:), x(2,:))
```

if you want all the combinations then check out `pdist2`. If you don't have the stats toolbox (i.e. no `pdist2`) then use `nchoosek` to create all possible pairs of rows:

```
I = nchoosek(1:size(x,1),2);
D = RGB_dist(x(I(:,1),:), x(I(:,2),:))
```

by the way, if you want to use `pdist` or `pdist2` then you will have to alter your function to be able to find the distance between one observation and a list of observations in one shot. The easiest way is to replace your `-` with `bsxfun` like this:

```
sqrt(sum(((bsxfun(@minus,x,y))*[3;4;2]).^2,2));
```

then you can go

```
D = pdist(x, @RGB_dist)
```

both methods give you

```
D =

     7
     1
     1
     7
     6
     8
     0
     2
     6
     8
```

or

```
squareform(D)

ans =

     0     7     1     1     7
     7     0     6     8     0
     1     6     0     2     6
     1     8     2     0     8
     7     0     6     8     0
```

But this is probably wrong as this squares after multiplying by the weights. You probably don't want that so I think your final function should look like that in Divakar's answer

Comment: @Dan This is great! But I do not understand why your output is different that that obtained by Divarak. Could you please explain in some other way? Or provide an example to be more clear?

Comment: @TanatosDaniel So the reason is because Divakar noticed that you are implementing your formula incorrectly. My output is the same as your *code* where as Divakar's answer is the same as your *formula*. I would venture that Divakar's answer is what you actually want. The difference is that you first multiply by weight and then square i.e. **((x-y)*w)^2** where as Divakar and the maths says square first then multiply i.e. **((x-y)^2)*w**

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) twice (once for the subtraction and once for applying the weights):

```
weights = [3 4 2];
d = squeeze(sqrt(sum(bsxfun(@times, ...
    bsxfun(@minus, x.', permute(x, [2 3 1])).^2, weights(:)))));
```

Comment: I was typing out this approach too! +1

Answer (score 4):

One approach based on **[`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)** and **[`pdist2`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/stats/pdist2.html)** -

```
%// Input RGB matrix
x=[62,29,64;
    63,31,62;
    65,29,60;
    63,29,62;
    63,31,62;];

Wgts = [3 4 2]; %// Weights
weuc = @(XI,XJ,W)(sqrt(bsxfun(@minus,XI,XJ).^2 * W'));
out = pdist2(x,x, @(Xi,Xj) weuc(Xi,Xj,Wgts)) %// output
```

Output -

```
out =
         0    5.1962    7.6811    3.3166    5.1962
    5.1962         0    6.0000    4.0000         0
    7.6811    6.0000         0    4.4721    6.0000
    3.3166    4.0000    4.4721         0    4.0000
    5.1962         0    6.0000    4.0000         0
```

According to the smart comment posted by @Luis, it seems like in the final step you can use - `out = squareform(pdist(x,@(Xi,Xj) weuc(Xi,Xj,Wgts)))`, which might be a bit faster, but no promises as no proper runtime benchmarks were done. The concepts `squareform`  and `pdist` are introduced in [Dan's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24405230/3293881), so credit to him for that. But the values seem different, so I am only guessing that the second input to `pdist` aren't the same between these two solutions.

Comment: +1 Perhaps use `squareform(pdist(x,...))` instead of `pdist2(x,x,...)` to spare some computations?

Comment: Thanks @Luis! Might be a bit faster and added to the solution!

Comment: Actually I just saw @Dan also uses `pdist` - `squareform` in his answer, so some credit should go to him as well :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo That's a mess!! Well of course I have attributed it, but now it feels wrong sorta :)